# Using Secrets in Composite Actions GitHub

Tags: github-actions

I am creating a composite action and I am trying to use the secrets supplied by GitHub but  I am running into errors stating that secrets are not found.

This could be recreated with your action.yml looking like:

```
name: 'test'
description: 'test'
runs:
  using: 'composite'
  steps:
    - name: Create Branch
      run: echo "git branch test"
      env:
        GITHUB_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}
      shell: bash
```

The composite actions seem to have no knowledge of secrets which make it hard to run git commands via them.

Comment: you need to pass these secrets via inputs. there's a good reason for that: imagine if an action you're calling could use your secrets without you passing them to the action.

Comment: reusable workflows do take secrets and we need to pass them manually as well, so I don't see a good reason why actions can't do the same

Answer (score 46, accepted):

As [rethab](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1080523/rethab) stated in the comment above. If you need to use secrets inside an action, those secrets need to be informed via action inputs.

In your case, the `action.yml` file should look like this:

```yaml
name: 'test'

description: 'test'

inputs:
  token:
    description: 'A Github PAT'
    required: true

runs:
  using: 'composite'
  steps:
    - name: Create Branch
      run: echo "git branch test"
      env:
        GITHUB_TOKEN: ${{ inputs.token }}
      shell: bash
```

GHA works this way for a security reason, as you wouldn't need the consent from the users to manipulate their repository secrets if it was possible to manage them directly inside some actions.

That way, you guarantee the user will need to inform the secret and give this access from its workflow when using the action.

Comment: Reusable workflows has `secrets` but actions are limited to `inputs`.

Comment: How do we pass these in to the action YML once we set them?

Comment: I suggest to check the [documentation](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/creating-actions/creating-a-composite-action) Jackie. You'll see example of how to build and how to use those composite actions (with or without inputs)